# Solving token error in js

Tags: javascript

At the moment when I try to run(using node):

```
import React from 'react';
import './HeaderSection.css';

//The home screens upper section displaying the appname, studentID, etc.
const headerSection = (props) => {

    timetable(){
        var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    }

    return (
        <div className="HeaderSection" >
            <h1 className="AppName"></h1>
            <h4 className="StudentID">{props.studentID}</h4>
            <button className="ChangeButton" onClick={props.onClick}>Change</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default headerSection;
```

I get the error:  Unexpected token, expected ; (7:15)

Comment: @Raywengay - Will means that the parentheses indicate the line number and the character position on the line that the code is potentially causing the problem. (7,15) - 7th line, 15th character. You didn't provide that code.

Comment: Or, you did, but we can't tell without examining each and every character.

Comment: It's exactly how it is on here. There is a red arrow underneath the opening '{' for timetable in cmd

Comment: You're missing the `function` keyword in front of `timetable`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `function` keyword in front of `timetable`.  Right now your code reads like you're *invoking* `timetable`, but you're *declaring* it.  The compiler interprets it as an invocation, which is why it doesn't understand the following `{`.